# set order of dynamically created links

Tags: channel-entries, list, dynamic

I have a list a dynamically created links in my sidebar.  I want one particular link to appear first in the list; the order after that is unimportant.  How could I accomplish this?  Here is my code:

```
<ul class="categories">
        <a href="{path=ministries}"><h2 class="section-header">Ministries</h2></a>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="ministries" dynamic="no" {gv_param_disable_all}}
        <li><a{if segment_2 == url_title || url_title =="get-involved" && segment_2 == ""} class="current"{/if} href="{homepage}/ministries/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>
        {/exp:channel:entries}      
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each link is an entry then you can set the one you want at the top to be "sticky". You can do this in the options tab of the entry form. It will then appear first in any list of entries regardless of other ordering set in the entries tag pair.

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#sticky

Otherwise you can order by date or use a third party add-on to manage the ordering.

You can also set a custom order on your entries tag-pair but this relies on you knowing the entry ids of the entries you are retrieving.

Comment: the "make entry sticky" option was exactly what I needed.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The quick and simple way is to set the **Entry Date** of your important link so it's later than all the other entries (or, very far into the future and then add `show_future_entries="yes"` to your Channel Entries tag).

The nicer way is to use [Low Reorder](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-reorder) to set the order of your entries.